# Soundcloud API returning a short URL - Javascript

Tags: soundcloud

I would like to tell the API to return a short url and echo the short url of the song, instead of the long url. For example snd.sc

I just can't find any documentation on this, can anyone point me into the right direction?

Thanks in advance!